# Single thread one to one chat in xmpp

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I am trying to build a chat application with xmpp. I am using openfire. But the messages between two parties are not binding in one chat thread.

Here is a code :

```
`let message = "Yo!"
  let senderJID =  XMPPJID(string: "\(opponentName)@\(domainName)")
  let msg = XMPPMessage(type: "chat", to: senderJID)
  let threadId : String = "uniqueID"
  msg.addThread(threadId)
  msg.addBody(message)
  stream.send(msg)`
```

Here i am using unique thread between two clients but in xmpp database messages are not clubbing in one chat thread.